# MFC: How to include a custom control into Visual Studio's toolbox

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, mfc

Is this feature possible for custom MFC controls in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to [package it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165358%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for use with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but this method requires that i build my custom control as an external dll. Isn't it possible to add a custom control to VS's toolbox without creating an external dll ?

Comment: I don't believe so. It's the same sort of methodology Microsoft used in earlier versions of Visual Studio for user ActiveX controls.